# Product model hasCustomOptions function is not working in CE 1.7.0.2

Tags: product, custom-options, simple-product

I have facing problem regarding to custom option.

I have load a product  by

```
$CustomProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
 if ($CustomProduct->hasCustomOptions()) {
echo $CustomProduct->getName();
 }
```

This product have already have custom options.The function `hasCustomOptions() is not working`

[image]

Comment: Did you rebuild your indexes?

Comment: yes, i have done indexes ,but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following snippet:

```
if ($CustomProduct->getHasOptions()) {
    echo $CustomProduct->getName();
}
```

As this is what is built after the product is loaded and not the customOptions

```
/**
 * Load product options if they exists
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    parent::_afterLoad();
    /**
     * Load product options
     */
    if ($this->getHasOptions()) {
        foreach ($this->getProductOptionsCollection() as $option) {
            $option->setProduct($this);
            $this->addOption($option);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I could be wrong but simply options are the options themselves but custom options are the user's choices for these options as you can see these are built when `_prepareProduct` from a buy request.

Comment: Thanks for  you concept.after a lot of time spend i have understand......Thanks give you upvote... and accept your answer